# Not loading CSS files after login to my sitecore instance

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.2

Refused to apply style from 'sitecore/shell/client/Applications/LaunchPad/LaunchPad.css' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

getting this error in console after login in to my sitecore instance.

Getting the page like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh0bb.png)

all the files are in correct place only, I have verified.